# Rails: Attribute and method for two unrelated classes: Best DRY approach?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, module, dry

This is an almost trivial problem but I want to follow (and learn more about) Rails best practices, in particular the DRY principle.

My app handles two unrelated classes, Countries and Places; both have an attribute `name`. In views, I use their name in titles etc., e.g. `"Visit #{@country.name}"`.

In most instances, that works. But some Countries and Places require "the" as a prefix. Example: "Visit Netherlands" sounds clunky and wrong, so it must be "Visit the Netherlands". Yet in lists and search results, it is supposed to be "Netherlands", without "the".

If it were only one class that's affected, I would

- add a boolean column `prefix` to its table
- add a method called `name_prefixed(uppercase=false)` that would take `name` and, if `prefix` is `true`, prepend "the"/"The" (depending on the value of `uppercase`)
- replace `@country.name` with `@country.name_prefixed` where applicable

However, since the issue exists with two unrelated classes, how would I best take care of this without repeating myself?

Comment: You could easily share a method between two models, or use a view helper.  That way you won't repeat yourself. The common way to share methods between models is including it as a module or concern http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html  However seems like this prefix column would have to go into both tables in your current architecture.

Comment: Thanks. I've put it into a module, into the app/models folder, and used `include NamePrefixer` in both Country and Place. Works like a charm!